# Facebook Business Name Not Extracting

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am struggling to pull off business names from Facebook. I can pull all the other data off fine, just not the business name. I have been trying different variations for several days but can not work it out. I have tried adding `.Children (0)` Also Tried "Tag" `.getElementsByClassName("_64-f")(0).getElementsByTagName("Span")(0)` Also Tag with child  `.getElementsByClassName("_64-f")(0).getElementsByTagName("Span")(0).children (0)` I have also tried `Id` and then navigating the children

I do not get any errors if the code is as below, it just places a hyphen into the cell. For the other variations I get  error messages `object variable or with block variable not set`  or `object doesn't support this property or method`

Link = [Facebook Link](https://www.facebook.com/pg/BMWParkLane/about/)

**Q)** What is the right element?

```
    lastrows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Sheet20.Range("B5").Value = lastrows - 1
  End With

    Counter = 0
    For Each link In varLinks
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        DoEvents
        Set doc = NewHTMLDocument(CStr(link))
'''''Element 1 Column B
        If doc.getElementsByClassName("_64-f")(0) Is Nothing Then
            wsSheet.Cells(StartRow + myCounter, 2).Value = "-"
        Else
            wsSheet.Cells(StartRow + myCounter, 2).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("_64-f")(0).innerText
        End If
```

```html
<div class="fb_content clearfix " id="content">
  <div>
    <div class="clearfix">
      <div class="_1qkq _1qks">
        <div class="_lwx" style="position: relative; height: 762px;">
          <div class="_r_m _6ye8" role="navigation" aria-labelledby="u_0_0_OF" id="entity_sidebar" style="width: 180px; top: 0px; position: absolute;">
            <div id="u_0_d_UA">
              <div class="_6taw">
                <div class="_6taw">
                  <div class="_6tax">
                    <a aria-label="Profile picture" class="_2dgj" href="/225094634174032/photos/3538030452880417/" rel="theater">
                      <div class="_6tay" style="width: 172px; height: 172px;"><img class="_6tb5 img" src="https://scontent-lhr8-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p320x320/92570293_3538030462880416_7204788388996579328_n.jpg?_nc_cat=107&amp;ccb=3&amp;_nc_sid=dbb9e7&amp;_nc_ohc=YoMPonz_koAAX-cvM6g&amp;_nc_ht=scontent-lhr8-1.xx&amp;tp=6&amp;oh=193586eb8fad5e292e7cc65ac6645668&amp;oe=605D4D63"
                          alt="" width="172" height="172"></div>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="_19sz">
              <div class="_19s-">
                <div id="u_0_e_lO">
                  <div>
                    <div style=""><span><div id="u_0_0_OF">
                       <span class="_33vv">
                         <a class="_64-f" href="https://www.facebook.com/BMWParkLane/">
                          <span>BMW Park Lane</span></a>
                      </span><span class="_3d2h"></span></div>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="_19s_">
```

**Image of what I am after**
[image: FB Image Business Name]

**Results**

[image: FB Results]

'''' Updated Today 26/2/2021

IE no longer works with FB so using this

```
Public Function NewHTMLDocument(strURL As String) As Object
''' Function For FB
    Dim objHTTP As Object, objHTML As Object, strTemp As String
    
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    objHTTP.setOption(2) = 13056
    On Error Resume Next
    objHTTP.Open "GET", strURL, False
    objHTTP.send
    On Error Resume Next
    If objHTTP.Status = 200 Then
        strTemp = objHTTP.responseText
        Set objHTML = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        objHTML.body.innerHTML = strTemp
        Set NewHTMLDocument = objHTML
    Else
        'There has been an error
    End If
End Function
```

''' ######## ###### Update Again today   ###############

Originally I used IE and the class as stated in my above code and it pulled of the details, this is an old search result. Since IE nolonger works with Fb I changed it to the above, but used the same class. Only this class does not work

[image: Old Search Results]

Old code which worked on IE

```
   If doc.getElementsByClassName("_64-f")(0) Is Nothing Then
      wsSheet.Cells(Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "B").Value = "-"
   Else
      dd = doc.getElementsByClassName("_64-f")(0).innerText
        Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "B").Value = dd
   End If
```

'''' ########### updated today at 4:50 uk time #########

Since Zwenn has advised that this data can not be taken off, I have been attempting a work around, by taking off the outerHtml and the trimming it. However as usual I am stuck.

So far I have done this, changed the class to get outerHTML

```
'''''Element 1 Column B
       If doc.getElementsByClassName("_2yau")(0) Is Nothing Then
            wsSheet.Cells(StartRow + myCounter, 2).Value = "-"
        Else
            wsSheet.Cells(StartRow + myCounter, 2).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("_2yau")(0).outerHTML
        End If
```

Outer Html

```
<A class=_2yau href="about:/cjwebdev/?ref=page_internal" data-endpoint="/cjwebdev/?ref=page_internal"><SPAN class=_2yav>Home</SPAN><SPAN role=progressbar aria-busy=true aria-valuetext=Loading... class="img _55ym _55yn _55yo _2wwb" aria-valuemin=0 aria-valuemax=100></SPAN></A>
```

I have then attempted to strip out the business name with is between the `/`

```
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wsSheet = wb.Sheets("Facebook")
     wsSheet.Columns(b).Value = Left(myString, InStr(2, myString, "/", vbTextCompare) - 1)
```

I can get the outerHtml, However I am no good at triming/stripping the details which are FROM `A class=_2yau href="about:/cjwebdev/?ref=page_internal` to `cjwebdev`

Any help will do - Thanks

Comment: Hi Sharid. If the IDs are always the same, you should get what you want with `doc.getElementByID("u_0_0_OF").innerText`

Comment: Thanks Zwenn, but that did not work

Comment: The IDs and class names are changing at different page calls. I think the ID `entity_sidebar` is stable. Try `ie.document.getElementByID("entity_sidebar").getElementsByTagName("a")(1).innerText` But what do you use to load the HTML? A call in the IE changes to Edge.

Comment: Zwenn, this is good, however it pulls an element from the sidebar menu and not the business name. I did try to set the `(1)` to `(0)` and that pulled the innertext `"Home"`. I also had to change `ie.document.get` to `doc.get`

Comment: I wrote a little test script and copy the line from there. Thats why you must change to `doc`. Does it work now? If not please tell me what you use to load the page. It's not the IE I think.

Comment: see new update ABOVE, not using IE as it no longer works with FB

Comment: If you take a look at the HTML you get via the xhr, you can see that the data you want is not included. I think it is part of a JS to make it visible on the page. But JS doesn't work with xhr. With xhr you can only get static content, never dynamic.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I will have to remove this column, also how do you do this `If you take a look in the HTML you receive via the xhr you can see the data you want isn't inside`

Comment: In this case there is only less HTML. You can make it visible with `Cells(1, 1) = doc.getElementByID("entity_sidebar").outerHTML` in the first cell of the active sheet or `Debug.Print doc.getElementByID("entity_sidebar").outerHTML` in the direct window of the ide. If you need longer HTML parts you can save it to a text file. To show that I must write an answer. But it's off topic.

Comment: No, thats fine. If I knew how to do what you just said I could have saved a few days of work. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value is dynamically pulled from a script tag in the HEAD. I show you both how to:

1. Parse value direct with regex from .responseText
2. How to preserve the HEAD content of response, where target script tag resides, when passing into body.innerHTML of HTMLDocument variable. With the preserved response, I give the css selector to match the appropriate script tag by its `type` attribute and its value (script type selector not needed), in order to extract the string which you can parse with a json parser to get your desired value. I don't show the json parsing.

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetCompanyName()
    'tools > references > Microsoft HTML Object Library
    Dim re As Object, xhr As Object, html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, s As String

    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    re.Pattern = """LocalBusiness"",""name"":""(.*?)"""
    
    With xhr
        .Open "GET", "https://www.facebook.com/pg/BMWParkLane/about/", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        s = .responseText
        html.body.innerHTML = "<body>" & s & "</html>" 'to preserve Head
        Debug.Print re.Execute(s)(0).SubMatches(0)
        Debug.Print html.querySelector("[type='application/ld+json']").innerHTML  'View the script tag
    End With
```

---

Regex:

[image]

The difference from the above description is I haven't set multiline and global flags and have left as VBA defaults of regex object.

Comment: Very good. Thanks for remember me to have a look in the `head`. There is also a meta tag with the attribute `content` the name can be read from `<meta property="og:title" content="BMW Park Lane">`

Comment: @Zwenn True. Thank you. I went with the HEAD for the security of it being explicitly associated with local business name. I haven't seen enough urls to know if I made the right decision ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: `I haven't seen enough urls to know if I made the right decision ¯_(ツ)_/¯` Because your aproach is part of a JSON I think it is universal usable. But it is task of @Sharid to verify that for his purposes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am confused as when I inspected the page I didn't find `[type='application/ld+json']`. !!

Comment: I have exported the response text to a text file and I found the json response in the header but I couldn't find `application/ld+json`

Comment: @YasserKhalil  It is there in the response. See https://regex101.com/r/tsugbe/2

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Big thanks to Zwenn and QHarr for taking the time out to help. As always QHarr never disappoints and did some outstanding work, way out of my depth. QHarr's method is the answer I am accepting.

Another method is my work around, which was to get the outerHTML into the cell and then TRIM  it as it goes in so you only see the results

```
 Dim Cl As Range
        With Sheets("Facebook")
            For Each Cl In .Range("B2", .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
                Cl.Value = Split(Cl.Value, "/")(1)
            Next Cl
         End With
```

**Result**

[image: FB Results]